# switching between multiple views within one view controller

Tags: ios, uiview

I am going to ask my question in a few different ways in hopes of giving a better idea of what Im asking because it may seem quite confusing. I am also posting an explanation of what I am trying to do.

So firstly, How can I switch between multiple views within one view controller?

Secondly, If I have four views (A, B, C, and D) how can I have view A visible and when a button on view A is selected it will fade out into the selected view, for example I may have a button "button B" and when this button is pressed, view A would fade out (see code below) and view B would become visible.

I don't want any "black screen" animations to take place (this is why I am not using multiple view controllers), I want the view switching to be done in the background and have the menu (view A) visible the whole time then the menu will fade out once the view (view B,C, or D) has been switched.

to give you an idea of how I would like to use this ability I have the following explanation:

currently I have one view with a menu that fades in with a pinch and fades out with the opposite gesture. I would like to have this function connected to several views within one controller so that I may seamlessly fade in and out of the menu to different views. here is a step by step process of what I mean:

1. pinch - fade into the menu
2. push button on menu
3. switch the view but stay in the menu.
4. fade out of the menu into the new view.

I have the code for the menu fade in and fade out here to give you an idea of what I'm talking about:

```
- (IBAction)ChangeAlpha:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender {


sender.scale = MIN(sender.scale, 62.5/_item1.frame.size.height);
sender.scale = MAX(sender.scale, 50/_item1.frame.size.height);

_item1.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_item1.transform, sender.scale, sender.scale);
_item2.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_item2.transform, sender.scale, sender.scale);
_item3.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_item3.transform, sender.scale, sender.scale);

sender.scale = 1;

menuAlpha = 5-((1/12.5)*_item1.frame.size.height);

_item1.alpha = menuAlpha;
_item2.alpha = menuAlpha;
_item3.alpha = menuAlpha;
_menuBackground.alpha = menuAlpha;

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    if (menuAlpha < .5) {

        CGFloat scale = (280/_item2.frame.size.width);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1-menuAlpha animations:^{
            _item1.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_item1.transform, scale, scale);
            _item1.alpha = 0;
            _item2.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_item2.transform, scale, scale);
            _item2.alpha = 0;
            _item3.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_item3.transform, scale, scale);
            _item3.alpha = 0;
            _menuBackground.alpha = 0;
        }];
    }

    else {

        CGFloat scale = (224/_item2.frame.size.width);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:menuAlpha animations:^{
            _item1.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_item1.transform, scale, scale);
            _item1.alpha = 1;
            _item2.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_item2.transform, scale, scale);
            _item2.alpha = 1;
            _item3.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_item3.transform, scale, scale);
            _item3.alpha = 1;
            _menuBackground.alpha = 1;
        }];
    }
}
```

}

If this question is still confusing please say so and I will edit it to clarify anything.

Thank you for your insight!

Edit: in response to Mr H, the code is to give you an idea of how I would like the user to be able to fade in and out of the menu view, the question alone has nothing to do with the code. It is just there as a tool to help understand what I am trying to do. Also I thought about your suggestion, but I couldn't think of a way to design each view separately in IB. could you please elaborate your comment as an answer? please address my concern about IB.

Edit 2: in response to danh, I have looked at the developer reference to which you refer and was hoping for an answer relating to this, but I am new to iOS dev. and it is a little hard for me to understand. could you suggest some tutorials on the topic?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand why there's so much code to do with affine transforms when your question is about switching views. Anyway a simple way to do this would just be to have all 4 views displayed simultaneously and you animate the fading of their alphas between 0 and 1 when you want one to appear or another to disappear etc.

Comment: It's kind of a broad question.  Might be useful to break it down into a few, each focussed on a particular effect you'd like to achieve.  Meantime, checkout the UIView class method transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Before going into some options though, let me say I think it is unadvisable to keep all the views in a single `UIViewController`. It will mostly likely creating an overly long, complex, file which will be hard to maintain. As far as not wanting a "black screen" in your animation. It's quite possible to do without one.

1. You could use one of the existing container view controllers (like `UITabBarController`). Don't want the `UITabBar` to be visible? Then hide it and changed the `selectedViewController` programmatically.
2. Setup in the Storyboard, use and "custom" segues which provide custom animations.
3. Turn your 4 views into `UIViewController`s (one for each view), then create your own container view controller which loads up and displays those 4 view controllers as needed. Your container view controller can contain all the animation code since view controllers are embedded in a `UIView`. While this is the most code, it offers the most flexibility and still keeps all your code properly encapsulated.